# I'm trying to deploy this code but always getting a: raise VirtualMachineError(e) from None VirtualMachineError: revert; or a index error

Tags: python, blockchain, solidity

```
from brownie import FundMe
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account

def fund():
   
    fund_me = FundMe[-1]

    account = get_account()

    entrance_fee = fund_me.getEntranceFee()

def main():

    fund()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and *ask a question*, in the question itself (not just the title). Explain what the code is intended to do; what steps you have tried in order to fix the error; and a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message - copied and pasted, from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end. You should also try to explain the context of the code - what is `brownie`? What are the `scripts.helpful_scripts`? - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because you have not deployed any FundMe contract, so the `FundMe[-1]` gave that error. You should try this:

```
# check whether you have deployed a contract a not
if FundMe:
    contract = FundMe[-1]
else:
    contract = deploy_contract(account)
```

Comment: Still not working, bro. I used that code and got the same "VirtualMachineErro: revert". I'm trying to figure it out for 2 day and nothing has worked. Do you have any other tip?

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with this and the thing that worked for me was deleting the "1337" folder under "deployments" and then redeploying the updated FundMe (with the getEntranceFee function added). I'm not sure why I had to do that since it should be using the most recently deployed contract. But I kept getting this error until I did that. Maybe deleting that folder caused the map.json to recompile, which I thought it was supposed to be doing every time anyways but maybe not.

He very briefly mentioned at one point that you might have to delete the build folder.

Comment: You're omitting a lot of information here: What's the "1337" folder and why is it there in the first place. Who's "he"? It seems that at best you're treating StackOverflow as your company's internal QA channel.